# why this routing configuration does not work?

Tags: windows-server-2008, routing

I have 2 VMs in HyperV role:

first is `RRAS` - it has 2 interfaces (both manually configured, no DHCP):

- 192.168.1.110 - "external" one, connected to the router
- 192.168.10.2 - that's internal interface which other VMs will be using as well

also I added VPN connection to our main server - and it gets 192.168.2.136 IP address in 192.168.2.XXX network. And IP route is create on the server as well for this interface.

second VM is called `KITCHENER`. It only has 1 interface

- 192.168.10.99 / 255.255.255.0, with default gateway set to `RRAS` server - 192.168.10.2

**QUESTION**: how can I ping "main server" - 192.168.2.1 - from the `KITCHENER` server when `RRAS` server is connected to VPN? please see screenshots with `ipconfig /all`, `route print` and `ping 192.168.2.1` commands. What needs to be done to get this working?

all servers are Windows 2008 R2 if that matters. All firewalls are turned off, no antivirus programs are installed - pretty much blank Win2008R2 installs.

this is `RRAS` server configuration:
[image]

tracert from `RRAS` server to MAIN server:
[image]

`KITCHENER` server configuration
[image]

Comment: A quick look; you need to implement split tunneling on your client... check Zeljko Medic's blog on how to set it up here: http://medicblog.net/?p=1028

Comment: Please also include a tracert to the main server

Comment: @MichelZ - i updated my question. But basically "main" server is just another end of VPN tunnel.

Comment: the tracert should be from the ktchener server

Comment: @MichelZ it's there as well - see the last screenshot, top right corner - new cool "pathping" command's output :)

Comment: @Fergus - that's how i had it from the very beginning - "Use default gateway on remote network" checkbox is OFF on VPN connection.